# cloud sql proxy equivalent on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-sql

Is there a Cloud SQL proxy equivalent for AWS? We would like to be able to access RDS instances with a similar simple network setup that is provided with the Google's Cloud SQL Proxy setup.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you straight up do not need SQL proxy to have the same experience in AWS. RDS Proxy is a thing, however, it's not quite what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Typically one would create an RDS database in a VPC (network).  Access to the instance in the VPC can be setup in various ways:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html

https://medium.com/@michalisantoniou6/connect-to-an-aws-rds-using-an-ssh-tunnel-22f3bd597924

In terms of the OP question for an RDS proxy, AWS has recently released RDS proxy to act as a layer in between client applications and the RDS database itself.
It's currently (Jan 2020) under preview release if I understand correctly.

The main use cases for RDS proxy appear to be around scaling performance for large numbers of connections.
It would not be likely to be "simpler" to setup RDS proxy than the existing tutorial/reference material on accessing RDS instances.

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/pricing/

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/amazon-rds-proxy-available-in-preview/